# Video component missing from Live Photos downloaded from iCloud.com

Tags: icloud, photos

I'm downloading photos from iCloud.com to a local backup in order to free up storage on my iCloud account.

I would like any live photos to be preserved in a way that allows me to import and restore them as fully functional live photos in the Apple ecosystem at a later date. This requires an image and a video component of each live photo in order to import them into the Photos app.

Some of the live photos I download from [iCloud.com/photos](https://icloud.com/photos) are missing the video component even though each live photo plays just fine in the browser. The only exception is when I try to share the live photo using an iCloud link, in which case it won't play when you open the link. The live photo icon in the top left corner is also missing in that case.

So far, it's happened to about a handful out of each batch of 1,000 live photos I've downloaded from the website. It also happens when I download the affected live photos individually.

I'm having trouble getting my Photos app to download originals to my devices, so I can't test if the live photos can be saved that way. I've also schedule a GDPR data request-based copy of my Photos, but that will take several days to become available.

Does anyone have any insight into what might be causing this?

Comment: I'm curious what you're having trouble with using the Photos app to download originals?

Comment: It's getting stuck at various stages. It appears to be a common issue if you search for it on Google. In my case, it won't download anything since before December last year. Some people suggest disabling and reenabling iCloud Photos or deleting and starting with a new Photos library, both of which require re-downloading everything you've already downloaded, but it's hit and miss. I haven't gotten beyond getting stuck at less than 50% progress after a few days of trying. iCloud.com is more responsive.